# Proper usage/modification of QString given that some functions are const and others non-const

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, constants, qstring

I am performing some operations on a QString to trim it down, but I don't want to affect the original string.  I am new to Qt and am confused about the proper way to use the various QString functions, since some are const, and others are not.  So far, this is what I have:

```
// this needs to be const so it doesn't get modified.
// code later on is depending on this QString being unchanged
const QString string = getString();
```

The methods I need to call are `QString::simplified()`, `QString::remove()`, and `QString::trimmed()`.  The confusing part is what is the correct way to do this given that `simplified()` and `trimmed()` are `const`, but `remove()` is not.  Keeping in mind that I to copy the original and make modifications directly to the copy, this is what I have:

```
// simplified() is a const function but no problem because I want a copy of it
QString copy = string.simplified(); 

// remove is non-const so it operates on the handle object, which is what I want
copy.remove( "foo:", Qt::CaseInsensitive );

// trimmed() is const, but I want it to affect the original
copy = copy.trimmed();
```

Is using `copy = copy.trimmed()` the right way to handle this case?  Will this accomplish my goal of having copy be trimmed() for the next usage?  Is there a better (more elegant, more efficient, more Qtish) way to do this?

I have checked the [QString Qt Documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html) and was not able to satisfactorily answer these questions.

Comment: From http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#simplified it looks like once you use `QString::simplified()` you would not also need to use `QString::trimmed()`.

Comment: @E.M. I need to remove any whitespace that was between "foo:" and the next piece of text.  After the call to `QString::simplified()` that should be limited to one space, but nonetheless I need that space removed.  I could call `QString::remove()` first, but that would mess up my original instead of getting me a copy :-O

Comment: Ah, yeah I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is simply for optimization reasons.

> Behind the scenes, `QString` uses implicit sharing (copy-on-write) to reduce memory usage and to avoid the needless copying of data. This also helps reduce the inherent overhead of storing 16-bit characters instead of 8-bit characters.

Often times I'll tack on a few different ones when they are returning a reference to the modified string to get an end result.  (The more elegant way...)

For example:

```
QString str = " Hello   World\n!";
QString str2 = str.toLower().trimmed().simplified();
if(str2.contains("world !"))
{
    qDebug() << str2 << "contains \"world !\"";
}
```

Here is more on implicit sharing:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/implicit-sharing.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: I suppose optimization issues makes sense, since implicit sharing would not necessarily work with `QString::remove()`, but it will always work with `QString::trimmed()`.  On the other hand, if that were true then `QString::simplified()` would not be const, since implicit sharing may not work.  Not a bad theory though, very likely could be the reason.  Thanks!

Comment: Would it be appropriate to say `str = str.toLower().trimmed().simplified();`?